# How to write a file in Flask on Vercel?

Tags: python, flask, vercel

I have created a Flask project and deployed it to Vercel.
I want to write a file and this is the code of mine.
The following code is working on the local environment but not on Vercel

```
@app.route('/write', methods=['GET'])
def index():
  text="hello world"
  base_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
  path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'uploads')
  if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
    
  with open(os.path.join(path, '1.txt'), 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
    
  f.close()
  return "ok"
```

When I run this code, I got this error.

> ```
> mkdir(name, mode)
> OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/task/api/uploads
> ```

How to write a file with Flask and Vercel?
I tried to do with Edge Config Storage but am not sure how to do it.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation, nowadays you can use [/tmp](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions#using-temporary-storage).

/tmp seems to be the only place in which you can write files because the filesystem of Serverless Functions is read-only.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged because links can easily change/die. You should edit the key information into your post here.

Answer (score -1):

Vercel does not allow files to be saved inside itself while running.

Databases can be used to store your data.
If all you need to store are strings it shouldn't be too complicated in any database, but unfortunately as far as I know the Vercel databases don't support Python yet.

At the time, I used [fauna](https://fauna.com/), which I know supports Python with a nice API, but there are many other databases that can fit, you just have to search.

List of supported databases: https://vercel.com/integrations#databases

Comment: Thanks, Avraham.
Have you got experience with storing files on AWS S3 in Flask?

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Comment: then how to write a file in Flask on Vercel?

Comment: As far as I know there is no possibility to write a file directly to Vercel while running. You need to use a third-party provider that will manage the files (AWS S3 sounds like an excellent option, I've never tried it though).